# How to generate code_128 barcode for string with Barby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, barcode

I'm currently using Barby gem with wrapper gem has_barcode to generate a bar code for a string I have : j5xvvcz.

Gemfile gems (mostly for those who are new to this solution)

```
#for barcode generation
gem "barby", "~> 0.5.0"
gem "has_barcode", "~> 0.2.0"
gem "rqrcode", "~> 0.4.2" #for qr code support
```

Code i have in my model

```
include HasBarcode

has_barcode :barcode,
            :outputter => :svg,
            :type => :code_93,
            :value => Proc.new { |p| "#{p.number}" }
```

Where i render it to screen:

If I try to generate a qr_code or a code_93, it all works, but nor code_128 or code_39 work, getting a **data not valid** message.
My worries is that code_93 won't get recognized in some devices since it seems it is not so widely adopted (from what i read [here](http://www.makebarcode.com/specs/speclist.html) 128 would be the best solution for this)

This seems to be something i might be doing wrong, since the code is valid for code_128 aparently as i tested it [here](http://www.racoindustries.com/barcodegenerator/1d/code-128.aspx).

Anyone knows what might be wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently mode 'A' for code_128 doesn't suit for smallcaps with Barby.

So i had to had mode B working.

Current published gem version of has_barcode forces mode 'A', so I added a little "home-patch", while adding a suggestion to github.

Here is my final has_barcode.rb file :

```
require "rubygems"
require "i18n"
require "active_support"
require "active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb"
require "active_support/inflector.rb"
require "barby"

require "has_barcode/configuration"

module HasBarcode
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:extend, ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def has_barcode(*args)
      options = args.extract_options!
      @@barcode_configurations ||= {}
      @@barcode_configurations[args.first] = HasBarcode::Configuration.new(options)

      define_method args.first do
        if options[:type] == :code_128
          @@barcode_configurations[args.first].barcode_class.new(options[:value].call(self), options[:code128])
        else
          @@barcode_configurations[args.first].barcode_class.new(options[:value].call(self))
        end
      end

      define_method "#{args.first}_data" do |opts|
        if opts
          send(args.first).send("to_#{options[:outputter]}", opts)
        else
          send(args.first).send("to_#{options[:outputter]}")
        end
      end

    end

    def barcode_configurations
      @@barcode_configurations
    end
  end

end
```

My model :

```
has_barcode :barcode,
              outputter: :svg,
              type: :code_128,
              code128: 'B',
              value: Proc.new { |p| "#{p.number}" }
```

and my view :

```
<%= my_model.barcode_data(xdim:2, height:60).html_safe %>
```

Do notice that at current date (2012-12-05) current gem isn't updated with latest changes that allow to pass outputter arguments like xdim and height.

This answer is based on latest code updates (issue related) and my own suggestion, and can be found [here](https://github.com/dpickett/has_barcode/issues?state=closed)

While this solution isn't embedded into the has_barcode gem, i will be using Barby directly:

In my model added :

```
def get_barcode(number)
     require 'barby'
     require 'barby/barcode/qr_code'
     require 'barby/outputter/svg_outputter'

     barcode = Barby::Code128B.new("#{number}")

     barcode.to_svg(xdim:2, height:60)
  end
```

in the view :

```
<%= my_model.get_barcode(my_model.number).html_safe %>
```

Comment: This displays the barcode and I want to display human readable text  as well below the barcode, How can I do it?